# react bootstrap Card component - how to not display image on mobile?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using the React Bootstrap Card component, and it looks fine on a browser, but on mobile the image gets squashed horribly, so I thought it would probably look better if it just didn't render it on mobile.

```
function RowCard({title, sub_title, post_text, image}) 
{
return (
    <Card style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>

        <Card.Img style={{width: "25%",objectFit: "cover"}} src={image} alt="banner" />
```

As an example this is the start of a function that produces a Card component given a struct with the relevant args.  I tried wrapping the <Card.Img..> line using BrowserView from react-device-detect, but this made the image tiny for some reason, and I tried importing isMobile from the same package, but wasn't sure how to actually make  use of it  (just doing if(!isMobile){<Card.Img...>} didn't work).

Can anyone provide any insight into how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can edit it with css by using media query for phone size

<Card.Img className="image" style={{width: "25%",objectFit: "cover"}} src={image} alt="banner" />

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .image{
    display: none  }
}
```

you can check it here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

but you can also just resize the image size to fit on mobile screen and also a good practice to design a responsive website

here are also some of the media queries for other screen sizes

```
   /* Media Query for Mobile Devices */
    @media (max-width: 480px) {
        body {
            background-color: red;
        }
    }
      
    /* Media Query for low resolution  Tablets, Ipads */
    @media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
        body {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
    }
      
    /* Media Query for Tablets Ipads portrait mode */
    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px){
        body {
            background-color: blue;
        }
    }
      
    /* Media Query for Laptops and Desktops */
    @media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1280px){
        body {
            background-color: green;
        }
    }
      
    /* Media Query for Large screens */
    @media (min-width: 1281px) {
        body {
            background-color: white;
        }
    }
```